# Problem with RecyclerView display and Null pointerException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I am facing NullPointerException and my App is crashing, if I place user.getImageURL!=null then image is not displayed

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        User user=mUser.get(position);
    holder.username.setText(user.getUsername());
   if(user.getImageURL().equals("default"))
    {
        holder.pic.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    }
    else
    {
        Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImageURL()).into(holder.pic);
    }


}
```

I am facing NullPointerException and RecycleViewer complication

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    mUser.clear();
    for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {

        User user=snapshot.getValue(User.class);
            assert user !=null;
            assert firebaseUser !=null;
       if(!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()))
        {
            mUser.add(user);
        }
    }


    userAdapter=new UserAdapter(getContext(),mUser);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
}
```

Please guide me if I could make any changes.
And yeah I removed .setHasFixedSize(true) too, but no use.

This is my code:-->
UserModel:

```
    public class User {
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String imageURL;

    public User(String id, String username, String imageURL) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public User() {

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }
}
```

UserAdapter:

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.sannith.androidchats.MessageActivity;
import com.example.sannith.androidchats.Model.User;
import com.example.sannith.androidchats.R;

import java.util.List;

public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<User> mUser;

    public UserAdapter(Context mContext,List<User> mUser)
    {
        this.mUser=mUser;
        this.mContext=mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_item,parent,false);
        return new UserAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            User user=mUser.get(position);
        holder.username.setText(user.getUsername());
       if(user.getImageURL().equals("default"))
        {
            holder.pic.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        }
        else
        {
            Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImageURL()).into(holder.pic);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUser.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView username;
        public ImageView pic;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            username=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username2);
            pic=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pic2);
        }
    }
}
```

UserFragment:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.sannith.androidchats.Adapter.UserAdapter;
import com.example.sannith.androidchats.Model.User;
import com.example.sannith.androidchats.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class UsersFragment extends Fragment {
        private UserAdapter userAdapter;


        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private List<User> mUser;

        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users,container,false);

        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        mUser=new ArrayList<>();

        readUsers();

        return view;
    }

    private void readUsers()
    {
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUser.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {

                    User user=snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        assert user !=null;
                        assert firebaseUser !=null;
                   if(!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()))
                    {
                        mUser.add(user);
                    }
                }


                userAdapter=new UserAdapter(getContext(),mUser);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code where you are adding items into array

Comment: Check if you are getting data in user.getImageUrl() in LOG

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: Well, it is being added into list without if condition --> mUser.add(user) where mUser is the Array list, but but but... My account is also being added so I stated the condition if user.getId is not equals to firebaseuser.getUid : if(!user.getId.equals(firebase.getUid)).

Comment: Alright,, i posted the whole code,please check if there are any blunders, i mean the situation is quite vexed as the studio is not able to find errors.

Comment: Does imageURL variable matches entity name which holds that image url in firebase database ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `User` object can have `imageUrl` as null. So you would need to check if it is not NULL before comparing it to something:

```
String url = user.getImageURL();
if (url != null && url.equals("default")) {
    holder.pic.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
}
```

Comment: I tried this if(user.getImageURL()=!null && user.getImageURL.equals("default")) --> it stopped chrashing but the pic is not being displayed.

Comment: because URL is NULL. Do you have it in User's object in Firebase?

Comment: Let me be more specific,Mam can you please view the whole code i updated in my question blog on above?

Comment: @Sannith i do not see your firebase data. Can you send screenshot? I think if you get the `user` object and it is not null and `id` is not null then it exists, but the image url is not there

Comment: even when there is a user's image URL... one has to fetch the image in order to display it.

Comment: Can you please text why the recycler view is not displaying any users?

Comment: You might want to wirte this `userAdapter=new UserAdapter(getContext(),mUser);`  and 
    `recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);` outside `onDataChange`.

Comment: Agree with @paragpawar. You need to create adapter and `onDataChange` you just call `notifyDatasetChanged`

Comment: But I am facing null pointer Exception at if(!user.getid.equals.(firebaseurser.getUid) I mean how it turned to be null?

Comment: Can you image of firebase database structure

Comment: You mean, the image from firebase Console, sir?

Comment: @Sannith yes! structure of Firebase database object which is equal to the user

Comment: What exactly you're trying to do with ths code ... because it seems you should be using childEventListener

Comment: Unable to add picture so here is the structure                    Email: Sannith@gmail.com                                                                                  ID:  wxc.......                                                                                       Password:  password                                                                   User: Sannith

Comment: Where should I use the childEventListener?

Comment: And here  not structure but Id of firebase user equal to ID of user, if the ids are unequal then add the user, because if this condition is not applied then our current user account will also be added to the list.

Comment: The image is displayed but, the username is not displayed in the list.i can't post the pic because it says I need atleast 10 reputations inorder to post pics.